# How to reset text on QCustom3DLabel?

Tags: c++, qt, 3d, qt5, data-visualization

On the following I'm trying to change text of `QCustom3DLabel` but it doesn't change. So, any suggestion on how to deal with this?

```
MainWidget::MainWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    resize(800,600);
    auto vLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);

    auto graph = new Q3DBars;
    vLayout->addWidget(QWidget::createWindowContainer(graph));

    auto camera = graph->scene()->activeCamera();
    camera->setCameraPreset(Q3DCamera::CameraPresetIsometricLeft);

    graph->axes()[0]->setRange(0,5);
    graph->axes()[1]->setRange(0,5);
    graph->axes()[2]->setRange(0,5);

    label = new QCustom3DLabel;
    label->setText("123");
    label->setScaling({5,5,5});
    label->setPosition({1,1,1});
    graph->addCustomItem(label);

    auto timer = new QTimer;
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWidget::setText);
    timer->start(2000);
}

void MainWidget::setText()
{
    qDebug() << "settext";
    label->setText("1234567890");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to update your widget ?

Comment: You mean to call `update()` on the slot? I tried this but nothing different happens.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the code and problem was same for changing other properties too(for example background color didn't change either).

anyway, here i wrote a *not very clean* code that works for changing label text:

```
void MainWidget::setText()
{
   graph->releaseCustomItem(label);
   QCustom3DLabel* newlabel = new QCustom3DLabel(nullptr);
   newlabel->setScaling(label->scaling());
   newlabel->setPosition(label->position());
   newlabel->setText("1234567890");
   label = newlabel;
   graph->addCustomItem(label);
}
```

I don't know why, But `setText` alone could change value of text property , but had no graphical effect.

However, When i created a new instance of `QCustom3DLabel` and called `setText` for that, it worked fine. I just had to release the previous label from graph.